# Lookup filtering with jq

Tags: json, filtering, jq

Giving a JSON string like this,

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Arthur",
    "age": "21"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Richard",
    "age": "32"
  }
]
```

How to filter by name and get the age?
E.g., given the name being `"Richard"`, let `jq` return `"32"`. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ jq --arg name Richard '.[] | select(.name==$name) | .age' input.json
"32"
```

When using jq like this in Windows, the quoting would have to be appropriate for Windows.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the amazing fast reply. I tried to find the answer myself and was lead  into thinking `jq '.[] | select(.name)  | test("Richard"))'` by https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/json-and-jq, why it is not working? I get `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end`

Comment: BTW peak, a side question, any easy way to remove the quotation (`"`) from the return? I actually want `32`, but I always get quotation in any returns. Thus I asked for `"32"` in OP, to make it easier.

Comment: 1. test(_) requires a string input. 2. You could use the -r command-line option.